# Select form a lot of many-to-many relations at once best practice

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering what is the best approach to handle the following problem:

I've got a DB-Structure where many tables are linked to my Person table like this:

```
phone n-n person_phone_realtion n-n person n-n person_email_realtionn-n email
```

I want to query my tables and parse the result to JSON and store the many to many values inside arrays. Is it better to make only one trip to the database and parse the result of my JOIN-query (see example below), which can be quite large due to duplicates, to my desired schema or should I make more trips to the database and keep the query result small?

What is the best practices for this scenario

Created with the following statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS phone CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS email CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person_phone_realtion CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person_email_realtion CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE phone (
    phon_id text  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT phone_pk PRIMARY KEY (phon_id)
);

CREATE TABLE email (
    emai_id text  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT email_pk PRIMARY KEY (emai_id)
);

CREATE TABLE person (
    pers_id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY (pers_id)
);

CREATE TABLE person_phone_realtion (
    pers_id int  NOT NULL,
    phon_id int  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE person_email_realtion (
    pers_id int  NOT NULL,
    email_id int  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO person(pers_id)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

INSERT INTO email(emai_id)
VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c');

INSERT INTO phone(phon_id)
VALUES ('D'),('E'),('F');

INSERT INTO person_email_realtion(pers_id, email_id)
VALUES (1,'a'),(1,'b'), (1,'c'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');

INSERT INTO person_phone_realtion(pers_id, phon_id)
VALUES (1,'D'),(2,'D'), (2,'E'),(5,'F');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS phone CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS email CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person_phone_realtion CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person_email_realtion CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE phone (
    phon_id text  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT phone_pk PRIMARY KEY (phon_id)
);

CREATE TABLE email (
    emai_id text  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT email_pk PRIMARY KEY (emai_id)
);

CREATE TABLE person (
    pers_id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY (pers_id)
);

CREATE TABLE person_phone_realtion (
    pers_id int  NOT NULL,
    phon_id int  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE person_email_realtion (
    pers_id int  NOT NULL,
    email_id int  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO person(pers_id)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

INSERT INTO email(emai_id)
VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c');

INSERT INTO phone(phon_id)
VALUES ('D'),('E'),('F');

INSERT INTO person_email_realtion(pers_id, email_id)
VALUES (1,'a'),(1,'b'), (1,'c'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');

INSERT INTO person_phone_realtion(pers_id, phon_id)
VALUES (1,'D'),(2,'D'), (2,'E'),(5,'F');
```

Now I can query all the relations at once using JOIN which would result in a lot of duplicate content:

```
SELECT * FROM person
RIGHT JOIN person_phone_realtion
ON person.pers_id = person_phone_realtion.pers_id 
RIGHT JOIN phone
ON person_phone_realtion.phon_id = phone.phon_id
RIGHT JOIN person_email_realtion
ON person.pers_id = person_email_realtion.pers_id
RIGHT JOIN email
ON person_email_realtion.email_id = email.emai_id;
```

where I will get a result similar to this:

```
pers_id phon_id emai_id
1       D       a
1       D       b
1       D       c
2       E       b
2       D       b
```

The resulting JSON should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "person" : 1,
        "email": [
            "a", "b", "c"
        ],
        "phone":[
            "D"
        ]
    },
    {
        "person" : 2,
        "email": [
            "b"
        ],
        "phone":[
            "D", "E"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please describe what you want in the result set.  Do you really want a dump of all the data in the database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the JSON-Schema I want to achive in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trip to the database is usually best.  You should pre-aggregate the values along each dimension:

```
select p.*, pp.phones, pe.emails
from person p left join
     (select pers_id, array_agg(ppr.phone_id) as phones
      from person_phone_realtion ppr 
      group by pers_id
     ) pp
     on p.pers_id = pp.pers_id left join
     (select pers_id, array_agg(per.email_id) as emails
      from person_email_realtion ppr 
      group by pers_id
     ) pe
     on p.pers_id = pe.pers_id ;
```

You can aggregate into strings or JSON, if you prefer.

Comment: Wow thanks! That helped a lot. I didn't know that you could aggregate data in SQL and your example did the trick.